# c++ passing a rhs object as parameter to the constructor of anther obejct

Tags: c++

I have searched the internet and SO for couple of hours on this question. There are similar questions but I could not find an answer to mine. Basically I am trying to pass a rhs object as a parameter of the constructor of another class. I did not receive any errors but neither of the two class's constructors are triggered. If I break the process into two steps: creating one object first and then pass it to the other as lhs, then it works. I tried to have a copy constructor with class2 below and it dose not work either.

Below is the coding. The program runs without errors, but the console records no output.

```
struct class1
{
    class1()
    {
        std::cout << "class1 constructed" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct class2
{
    class2()
    {
        std::cout << "class2 default constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename T>
    class2(T)
    {
        std::cout << "class2 with template constructed" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
     class2 test(class1()); 
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: That isn't doing what you think it is. Google *C++ most-vexing parse*.

Comment: `warning C4930: 'class2 test(class1 (__cdecl *)(void))': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)`  Add extra parens: `class2 test((class1()));`

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the tip. I got it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks I think that post is helpful. I would argue even though my question may be duplicate, but it was asked in a meaningfully different way:).

Comment: It's not like your question will go away if it is marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue.

`class2 test(class1());` is not a variable definition (as you might expect), but a function declaration, the function is named `test` and returns `class2`, takes one unnamed parameter which is a pointer to function (which takes nothing and returns `class1`).

You can use braces instead (since C++11). e.g.

```
class2 test(class1{});
```

Comment: got you seems like I should really get used to use the universal initialization list.

Answer (score 1):

```
class2 test(class1());
```

In this line 
Parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration